# How to know when ul too small for li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make a responsive template like bootstrap, and i am trying to find a way to know if the ul is getting too small for the li elements.
I have a ul like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Element one</li>
    <li>Element two</li>
    <li>Element three</li>
    <li>Element four</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the picture below, the ul(red line) is taking the whole page width:
[image: Ul]

And i want to do something if the ul's width equals that of the li elements.

Sorry, if this post is not the most easy to understand one.

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan As I am getting your concern, you need to set the width of ul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-calculate the minimal width (the width that the li elements require in order not to break), and simply set the min-width to the ul:

```
ul {
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

If you want to do something more when it reaches that size, you can use JavaScript to set a window resize listener in which you'd check the width of your ul element, and take appropriate measures based on its width.

---

See this simple example:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('d');
var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li')
var requiredWidth = 0;
var padding = 100;

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  requiredWidth += lis[i].offsetWidth;
}

// make the ul red if it's not as wide as the width of lis plus the padding
function handleSize() {
  if (ul.offsetWidth < requiredWidth + padding) {
    ul.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
    ul.style.background = "";
  }
};

window.onresize = handleSize;
handleSize();
```

```css
#d {background: #eee} 
#d li {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<ul id="d">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<p>Go "Full Page" and then try shrinking the window size to below ~908 pixels</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, but remember this will be a open source template, and some users will put more li elements than 4.

Comment: I couldn't have known that. You can use JS to calculate the required width dynamically.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, updated my answer with a simple example that changes colours depending on the width of its li children elements. You can do pretty much anything using this approach.

Comment: I'm going to try this later, i got to go.

Answer (score 0):

ul is a block element that takes full width if no style is given. But if you want to limit the ul width's to it's li elements, you can simply make the ul element an inline element using display property.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Element one</li>
    <li>Element two</li>
    <li>Element three</li>
    <li>Element four</li>
</ul>

 // Style
.navigation{
    display: inline;
 }
```

Comment: I believe OP wants the ul to be a block, but handle it differently when the lis inside start breaking into multiple rows (not enough width to fit).